# Check figure placement with \if statement

Tags: floats, positioning, conditionals

I would like to add a

```
\noindent
```

before a new paragraph but only if a floating figure is placed directly above it.

How can I check this using an \if-statement?
So looking at the example below I don't what the lower paragraph to be indented
if the figures is placed between the two paragraphs.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{resources/images/illustration.png}
\caption{illu}
\label{fig:my_illu}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\noindent
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.
```

Comment: No blank line before `\begin{figure}` and no blank line after `\end{figure}`.

Comment: If I don't use ```\\``` between the paragraphs they don't get seperated.
If I do use ```\\``` and the figure is not placed between the paragraphs I don't get an indent for the second one which is what I want.

Comment: Well, a new paragraph should be indented, in order to tell the reader about it.

Comment: It might me just a favor of mine, but I feel an indented paragraph beneath a figure looks wierd.

Comment: There are two cases; either the figure floats or it doesn't. In either case a new paragraph should be indented, like all the others. I can't think to a reason not to.

Comment: How/why are you using `\\`? A blank line in your source separates paragraphs. Please provide an MWE that shows your problem.

Comment: @egreg -- I believe that the OP likes paragraphs immediately following figures to be not indented like the first paragraph after a chapter heading (in some styles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most floats split paragraphs.  This assumes that you only want to `\noindent` the first paragraph after an `[h]` float.  Note that when `[h]` is one of the options, all of the other options will be on a later page.

It takes two runs for this to work.  This differs from egreg's solution in that the previous paragraph ends normally.

This particular example brings up the question whether you want to `\noindent` the next paragraph if it is at the top of the next page?  If not, you should use `\page@oddpage` and `\checkoddpage` from the ifoddpage package instead of `\value{page}`.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\rule{1em}{9\baselineskip}% <9 on first page, >9 on second page.

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htbp]% [!] doesn't do what you probably think it does
\begin{center}% \centering preferred, but I guess you want the extra space
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{illu}
\label{fig:my_illu}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{fig:my_illu}\relax \noindent\fi
\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I set ```\begin{figure}[tbp]``` it doesn't quite work. Maybe because ```\ifnum\value{page}=...```checks if the figure is on same page. My figure gets placed on the top and therefore the condition is true.

Comment: As stated, this is only for floats which include the [h] option, which is the only kind where you know which paragraph is the next one.

Comment: I get that now. Thanks a lot.